# React Select option CSS not working in IE

Tags: reactjs

```
<select>
  <option className={optionFont} value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
  <option className={optionFont} value="lime">Lime</option>
  <option className={optionFont} value="coconut">Coconut</option>
  <option className={optionFont} value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
.optionfont{
    font-size:16px;
    padding-left:17px;
    padding-top:10px;
    height:30px
}
```

i am working on a drop down which is working fine.
i try to modify option height and padding position.
CSS working fine in chrome .but above CSS not applying in IE.
any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: Which IE version?

Comment: IE version 10...

Comment: Please share proper CSS, on which element is this CSS applied? Please make sure you are posting a [mre].

Comment: @kiner_shah i have modified code

Comment: Can you check IE console if you have any error?

Comment: @karthi, applying CSS to select tag will make the changes appear I guess. Actually, CSS with option tag works, but only font-size seems to be reflected.

Comment: @kiner_shah margin-left working fine.but unable to add space between option